# How would you have independent sibling height using flex/grid/table when height changes?

Tags: html, css

Let's say there is a row with X amount of columns. The starting height of these columns should all be the same and each of these columns may expand to change their height based off a click (for this case, hover will be used). Let's also assume the height is dynamic and never gets defined (in this example it will be for the sake of usability).

Here is the sandbox that demonstrates the problem: http://www.cssdesk.com/RkqHc

Code below:

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
}
.child {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
}
.child2 {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: blue;
}
.child2:hover {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Some Test Data
    Some Test Data
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  Test
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice that both columns are the same size because of the table/table-cell properties, but when hovering over the blue column the height of the red column increases as well. I've tried using flex and grid but reached the same conclusions.

How would one go about keeping a column's sibling (in this case, the red) its original height when the height of the column in question (blue) changes?

Is there a way to do this without using grid, flex, or table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just came across your post. In case you're still searching for an answer to this question, this is what you can do.

**Method 1:** Table

The thing with a table cell is that if even one cell in a row or column has a greater height/width, all cells in that row/column will adjust themselves to match that and make the table look consistent. So I don't think this is possible with a table.

---

**Method 2:** Flex

With flex, increasing the height of one element will increase the height of the parent container as well. Since the parent height increases, the heights of *all* other flexboxes in the container will also increase to match that.

To stop this behavior, you can use the `align-items`/`align-content` properties on the parent container to align the flexbox to `flex-start`, `flex-end` or `center`. This will maintain the original height of the flexbox, and position **all** flexboxes, except the one with the new height, at the top/bottom or vertical center of the parent container.

If you want different flexboxes to be positioned separately, you can assign them a `align-self` prop. which will have the same values mentioned above.

This is what it would look like:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.child, .child2 {
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  background-color: crimson;
}
.child2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
:where(.child2, .child):hover {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Some test data
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  Test
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Method 3:** Div

Not much to explain here.

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.child, .child2 {
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: crimson;
}
.child2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
:where(.child2, .child):hover {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Some test data
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  Test
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Method 4:** Grid

Very similar to flex implementation:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  color: white;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.child, .child2 {
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
.child {
  display: block;
  background-color: crimson;
}
.child2 {
  display: block;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
:where(.child2, .child):hover {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Some test data
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  Test
  </div>
</div>
```

So here you go. Hope this helped you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Been a while but I believe I figured out the 2nd method on my own after some trial and error. I don't think it's possible to do it with table either.